# moment.js javascript countdown to a live event

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to create a countdown timer to a live event.

The countdown to the event should be the same across all browsers/timezones because it would be a fixed point in time.

I have an example here -> https://codepen.io/KyleAtSlik/pen/XWdQKWB

```
function updateCountdown() {
  var futureDate = moment('2020-12-14T00:00:01.000'),
      currentDate = moment();

  // Days
  var days = futureDate.diff(currentDate, 'days');
  document.querySelector('.countdown__days-number span').innerHTML = '000'.substring(0, 3 - ('' + days).length) + ('' + days);
  currentDate.add(days, 'days');

  // Hours
  var hours = futureDate.diff(currentDate, 'hours');
  document.querySelector('.countdown__hours-number span').innerHTML = '00'.substring(0, 2 - ('' + hours).length) + ('' + hours);
  currentDate.add(hours, 'hours');

  // Minutes
  var minutes = futureDate.diff(currentDate, 'minutes');
  document.querySelector('.countdown__minutes-number span').innerHTML = '00'.substring(0, 2 - ('' + minutes).length) + ('' + minutes);
  currentDate.add(minutes, 'minutes');

  // Seconds
  var seconds = futureDate.diff(currentDate, 'seconds');
  document.querySelector('.countdown__seconds-number span').innerHTML = '00'.substring(0, 2 - ('' + seconds).length) + ('' + seconds);
  currentDate.add(seconds, 'seconds');
}
```

however upon viewing it on various other timezones the date appears to take into account the timezone difference rather than the acutal time to the event.

Has anyone come across this issue.

Comment: You should post runnable code here, not elsewhere. '2020-12-14T00:00:01.000' has no associated offset or timezone so is parsed as local, so represents a different moment in time in places with different offsets. I don't understand why you're adding days, hours, mins, etc. to a local time. Getting the difference between two dates is well covered in various questions.

Comment: Your results are how it's supposed to work. You have one event at one universal time which translates into different local times around the globe.

Comment: @Ouroborus—the event isn't at "one universal time", that's the problem. It's a local timestamp, so is a different instant in time in each different timezone/offset.